# How to embedd the User defined function within the Querybuilder (SQL SERVER 2008)

Tags: sql-server, function, query-builder

I have an User defined function which returns a value. I want to add this value to the Column of Select Query within the Query Builder? Can anyone Please help me with example.

Example:
'select sum(Marks) from StudentDB
group by StudentID'.

Now I want to add the value which is returned by a function called fn_bonusMark to Sum(Marks).Just I want to know the syntax to embedd this function within the Querybuilder.

Answer (score 0):

If you call a function, you have to specify its schema name:

```
select sum(dbo.fn_bonusMark(Marks)) from StudentDB group by StudentID
```

The schema name is optional for views, tables and procedures, but it's required for functions.

P.S. Not sure what you mean by "the Querybuilder".